# Variable Width Bar Plot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I'd like to produce an area/bar graph in R similar to this: 
[image: Plot from David MacKay's book "Sustainable Energy"]
*(plot from David MacKay's (excellent) book "Sustainable Energy")*

I honestly can't even find the proper name for a plot like this. It seems to be a bar graph with variable width bars. Certainty a powerful communication tool.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't any amount of `Adobe Illustrator` work put into it? :)

Comment: [this blog post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2-variable-width-column-chart/) might provide you with a solution.

Comment: @Arun, MacKay actually explains in the Acknowledgments that the figures were drawn with gnuplot and metapost. No Illustrator, no R. Hardcore.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this with base graphics. First we specify some widths and heights:

```
widths = c(0.5, 0.5, 1/3,1/4,1/5, 3.5, 0.5)
heights = c(25, 10, 5,4.5,4,2,0.5)
```

Then we use the standard `barplot` command, but specify the space between blocks to be zero:

```
##Also specify colours
barplot(heights, widths, space=0, 
        col = colours()[1:6])
```

Since we specified widths, we need to specify the axis labels:

```
axis(1, 0:6)
```

To add grid lines, use the `grid` function:

```
##Look at ?grid to for more control over the grid lines
grid()
```

and you can add arrows and text manually:

```
arrows(1, 10, 1.2, 12, code=1)
text(1.2, 13, "A country")
```

To add your square in the top right hand corner, use the `polygon`  function:

```
polygon(c(4,4,5,5), c(20, 25, 25, 20), col="antiquewhite1")
text(4.3, 22.5, "Hi there", cex=0.6)
```

This all gives:

[image]

---

Aside: in the plot shown, I've used the par command to adjust a couple of aspects:

```
par(mar=c(3,3,2,1), 
    mgp=c(2,0.4,0), tck=-.01,
    cex.axis=0.9, las=1)
```

Comment: @csgillespie amazing. If I didn't know better I'd think your plot was from the book. (But I am colorblind...)

Answer (score 18):

Inspired by the code from [the blog post](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2-variable-width-column-chart/) I mentioned above,

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("Alpha", "Beta", "Gamma", "Delta"), width = c(25, 50, 75, 100), height = c(100, 75, 50, 25))
df$w <- cumsum(df$width)
df$wm <- df$w - df$width
df$wt <- with(df, wm + (w - wm)/2)

library(ggplot2)
p  <- ggplot(df, aes(ymin = 0))
p1 <- p + geom_rect(aes(xmin = wm, xmax = w, ymax = height, fill = x))
library(grid) # needed for arrow function
p1 + geom_text(aes(x = wt, y = height * 0.8, label = x)) + 
     theme_bw() + labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) + 
     theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(),axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
     axis.text.y = element_blank(), legend.position = "none") + 
     annotate("text", x = 120, y = 83, label = "a Beta block") + 
     geom_segment(aes(x = 100, y = 80, xend = 80, yend = 75), 
     arrow = arrow(length = unit(0.5, "cm")))
```

[image: beta blocker]

Comment: (+1) The legends are kind of redundant here, aren't they?

Comment: The mentioned [Blog post link](http://learnr.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/ggplot2-variable-width-column-chart/), for the record. I'm glad there is a ggplot way