# ggplot2 - 100% stacked bar chart with variable width bars but no space gap or overlap

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have a 100% stacked bar chart with variable width bars, but I would like for there to be no space gaps between the bars or overlap between the bars. Here is my sample data  and output without the scale_x_continuous line.

[output chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlXkH.png)

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), group = c("L","R","L","R","L","R"),width = c(0.1,0.1,0.50,0.50,0.40,0.40), y = c(0.75,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.1))

pos <- 0.5 * (cumsum(df$width) + cumsum(c(0, df$width[-length(df$width)])))


g <-ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, width = width*2, fill = group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white" ) +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = pos)
g
```

I have referenced the following threads and wasn't able to get the solutions to work for my scenario:

[How to make variable bar widths in ggplot2 not overlap or gap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688376/how-to-make-variable-bar-widths-in-ggplot2-not-overlap-or-gap?noredirect=1&lq=1)

[Spineplots in ggplot or at least vertical labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028000/spineplots-in-ggplot-or-at-least-vertical-labels)

The 1st link isnt using a stacked chart, but solves for the gap issue on a standard bar chart. The 2nd link is exactly what I am looking for, but I cant recreate the solution with my sample data. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Update - I have tried to use ChatGPT to create a solution, and it was not able to

Answer (score 0):

The margin space over and around plots is controlled by the `expansion` argument of the `scale_y_x()` functions (in your case, `scale_y_continuous` and `scale_x_discrete`). It's called expansion because it's a multiplicative factor that adds space on top and below the bars, so setting the expansion to 0 will remove any extra space around your plot. Therefore, you can remove this expansion margin like this:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), group = c("L","R","L","R","L","R"),width = c(0.1,0.1,0.50,0.50,0.40,0.40), y = c(0.75,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.1))

pos <- 0.5 * (cumsum(df$width) + cumsum(c(0, df$width[-length(df$width)])))


ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, width = width*2, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0)) +
  scale_x_discrete(expand = expansion(0))
```

[image: Example result]

EDIT: To get the bars to touch each other, i.e., to plot bars that have no horizontal space between them, we can calculate their position on the x axis as follows:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(x = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"), group = c("L","R","L","R","L","R"),width = c(0.1,0.1,0.50,0.50,0.40,0.40), y = c(0.75,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.9,0.1))

df2 <- df |> 
  mutate(id = as.factor(x) |> as.numeric()) |> 
  mutate(x2 = id * (2-width))

ggplot(df2, aes(x = x2, y = y,  width = width*4, fill = group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", color = "white") +
  scale_y_continuous(expand = expansion(0)) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = df2$x, breaks = df2$x2, expand = expansion(0))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it! That solves one of my issues for sure! My other issue was that I would like for the bars to be touching, rather than having a gap between A & B and B & C. Do you see the solution for that as well?