# How to do horizontally connected bars with the width determined by a variable using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, width

I would like to reproduce a graph like this in ggplot. [image]

The main thing is how to make the bars attached to each other on the x-axes s.t. there is no space between the bars. So far, I have this:
[image]

produced by

```
ggplot(df.dat, aes(x=reorder(region, -CumHistpC), y=CumHistpC, width = Population/1000)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=region), stat="identity", position="identity") +
```

Has someone an idea how to reproduce this as in the upper figure?

Best,
intasys

Comment: Please provide `df.dat` in usable format. E.g. paste the output of `dput(df.dat)`.

Comment: Maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591167/variable-width-bar-plot. Think the key search term is "variable width bar plot"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Variable Width Bar Plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14591167/variable-width-bar-plot)